# Why are 2 sprites displaying instead of 1?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am making a fighting game for the first time and all was going well until when loading the sprite sheet of the players two images of the same sprite display on the screen instead of just one.

I know it is because of the loading of the sprite sheet, but I don't know how to load the physics to the player so the animations still work, but the second sprite sheet doesn't appear.

```
var player;
var cursors;
var anim;


class fightGame extends Phaser.Scene {
constructor(){
  super("fightGame");
}

preload(){
  this.load.spritesheet('programCode', 'assets/sprites/player/programador/spritesheet/spriteCoder.png', {frameWidth: 187, frameHeight: 360, endFrame:6});
}


create ()
{
    var platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'programCode').setScale(0.4);
    player.setBounce(1.2);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    this.anims.create({
      key: 'bounce',
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('programCode', { start: 0, end: 1 }),
      frameRate: 0.22,
      yoyo: true,
      repeat: -1
    });

    player.anims.load('bounce');

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'left',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('programCode', { start: 2, end: 6 }),
        frameRate: 0.355,
        repeat: -1
    });


    this.anims.create({
        key: 'right',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('programCode', { start: 2, end: 6 }),
        frameRate: 0.355,
        repeat: -1
    });

    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

}

update ()
{
    if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
        player.setVelocityX(-1);

        player.anims.play('left', true);
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
        player.setVelocityX(1);

        player.anims.play('right', true);
    }
    else
    {
        player.setVelocityX(0);

        player.anims.play('bounce', true);
    }

    if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down)
    {
        player.setVelocityY(-330);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Depending upon how I read your question I see a few different questions. Are you trying to get assistance with the spritesheet you're loading, adding physics to this, or something else?

Comment: I am trying to add a sprite, but when I add physics to one it appears two images, one with physics and one without. I am just trying to have one with physics. please.

Comment: Unfortunately with the code you've provided I can't replicate this. It looks like this is a modified version of what's through [part 7 of the official Phaser 3 tutorial](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part7), and with your tweaks it looks fine. Is there more to the code than you've provided above?

Comment: I am using phaser-3.12.0, will try with a newer version. I think the problem is in    
      player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'programCode').setScale(0.4);

Is like that line not only adds the physics to the sprite I want, it also adds a sprite. Do you know other ways to add physics to sprites?

Comment: If you look at part 5 of the tutorial that's what he's got as well. My first thought was to break it apart so that it's `player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'programCode'); player.setScale(0.4);`, but testing with that didn't impact anything.

Comment: when you loaded all the code did you try moving the sprite? because both start at the same origin but moving the top one reveals the other one that has no physics.

Comment: Yup. Can you post a working example of this either using the SO functionality or on a site like JSFiddle?

Comment: https://codepen.io/pedroadrian987/pen/NOMZwJ?editors=1010

Comment: there is the code I made for the game with sprites and all.

Comment: Thanks for including the code. I see the issue, as well as a few others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues:

First, you're starting your `fightGame` scene multiple times.

```
this.input.keyboard.on('keydown_ENTER', function(event) {
    spriteSelec.anims.pause();
    spriteSelec2.anims.pause();
    spriteSelec3.anims.pause();
    spriteSelec4.anims.pause();
    spriteSelec5.anims.pause();
    spriteSelec6.anims.pause();

    this.input.keyboard.on('keydown_ENTER', function(event) {
        this.scene.start('fightGame');
    },this);
}, this);
```

This could is currently in your `update`, but should instead be in the `create`. As it is now, this is binding to the <kbd>enter</kbd> key on every update, while you only want it to bind once.

Second, since you've accounted for the multiple scenes being loaded your animation `frameRate`s and `player.setVelocityX();` values will need to be tweaked. If you change the former to 10 and increase the latter by 100 you'll see it's a little smoother experience, but you'll need to tweak it further.

Binding events to keys multiple times is a pretty common issue, and is tricky to debug unless you step through the code; I find the old way of throwing a `console.log('create');` at the top of the `create` function to be an easy first step. :)

Comment: thanks, I will try that! you're a live saver!! thanks again James

Comment: Happy to help! :)